# Looping through list of dataframes with a group_by and piping function?

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes which I am trying to apply a script to which works for a single data frame. 
Part of the script uses both piping and group_by:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
group_by (col1) %>%
summarise(newcol = sum(col2))
```

I've tried various loops or variations with lapply but haven't been able to find a way for it to work with a lists of dataframes where it would be something along the lines of:

```
mylist2 <- mylist1 %>%
group_by (col1) %>%
summarise(newcol = sum(col2))
```

But obviously changed around to work with loops or lapply. I'm probably missing something simple here but would appreciate some help. Thanks

PS - I looked at providing the data from the lists but wasn't able to provide reproducible samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` way.

```
# generate some data
mylist1 <- replicate(2, data.frame(col1 = rep(letters[1:2], 2),
                                   col2 = 1:4), 
                     simplify = FALSE)

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
mylist1 %>%
  map(., ~ group_by(., col1) %>%
        summarise(new_col = sum(col2)))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  col1  new_col
#  <fct>   <int>
#1 a           4
#2 b           6

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  col1  new_col
#  <fct>   <int>
#1 a           4
#2 b           6
```

---

In `base R` you might try `lapply` and `tapply`

```
lapply(mylist1, function(x)
  tapply(X = x[["col2"]], INDEX = x[["col1"]], FUN = 'sum'))
#[[1]]
#a b 
#4 6 

#[[2]]
#a b 
#4 6
```

Comment: If data frames have same columns, binding them might be a good option too : `mylist1 %>% bind_rows(.id="id") %>% group_by(id, col1) %>% summarize_at("col2",sum)`